# Unique key parts not showing in Create Form Grails

Tags: grails, primary-key, unique

I have following Domain Class -

```
    class xyz {
    String name
    String version
    String vclass
    Date dateCreated

static constraints = {
    version(blank:false)
    name (unique: ['version'])
}

    static hasMany = [ yz: Yz ]
}"
```

when i create a record for it, i don't see an option to enter version, only name and vclass. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Grails, **version** is a special property of Domain classes used for `optimistic locking`. Rename your property to something other than version. You can read more about this in the [user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking).